# Can I dynamically link a binary build for linux to work with .Net and Mono

Tags: c++, .net, linux, dll, mono

I am trying to build an .Net application for Raspberry pi that uses SPI. The SPI driver for Windows 10 IoT was to slow. Therefore am I migrating the project to Linux using Mono (as my code is allready written in .Net)

Since I had a problem with SPI speed on Windows IoT I am thinking about writing the SPI code in c++ and link them dynamically to the .Net application. But I am having a hard time finding info online on how to do this. Does anyone here know?

To sum up the question. I want to run my .Net application on Linux with mono and dynamically link a library that I will write in c++.

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just make sure your C++ compiled .so is findable on the system (maybe by making sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable can find it). Then in your C# code:

```
[DllImport("LibraryName")]
private static extern void Foo();

// Call Foo() from C#
```

In your C++ code:

```
extern "C" void Foo()
{
    // do C++ stuff
}
```

At runtime, when you call Foo() from C#, mono will load the .so and find the function and invoke it.

All of the gory details are here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: Thx a lot for your help. I also needed to properly install the .so in the linux system. If any one else has problems this is how to do it.
1. put the .so in the /usr/local/lib folder
2. run sudo ldconfig from terminal
3. check if it installed properly with Nm -C --defined-only -g xxx.so. if you get any output it has installed. :)